# invalid values for current date are returned when trying to get the date in" EEEE MMM d, yyyy" format

Tags: java, android, date

i want to display the current  date in this format   Wednesday  march 28,2012  , i wrote a method to get this format but it gives invalid values of the date (since when i run the code it gives  Saturday  sep2,1933) why is that ? what is the error in my code?

this is my code:

```
public class AddExercise extends Activity
 {   
   private Date   exercise_date;
   private TextView   date_Txt;
   Calendar localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_exercise);

    int  year = localCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int  month = localCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = localCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    exercise_date = new Date(day, month , yr);
    date_Txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
    String  x=formatdate(exercise_date, "EEEE MMM d, yyyy");
    date_Txt.setText(x);
        }

        public static String formatdate(Date paramDate, String paramString)
  {
    String str;
    if (paramDate != null)
    {
      if (paramString == null)
        paramString = "MMMM dd, yyyy";
      str = new SimpleDateFormat(paramString).format(paramDate);
    }
    else
    {
      str = null;
    }
    return str;
  }     
     }
```

Comment: You have the parameters reversed for constructing the `exercise_date`. This is the constructor...`Date(int year, int month, int day)` although as ring bearer points out, it is deprecated. No reason you can't use it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is primarily because you are using deprecated `Date()` constructor.
It requires following Parameters:
year - the year minus 1900.
month - the month between 0-11.
date - the day of the month between 1-31.
But you are passing incorrect year altogether

Why don't you simply do this:

```
return new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy").format(localCalendar.getTime())
```

or better yet

```
return new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy").format(new Date()));
```

Instead of jumping through all the hoops?

Comment: Although that `Date` constructor is deprecated, that isn't 'primarily' the reason. If you'd looked at the OP's code, you'd have seen they have the parameters in the wrong order. Deprecation doesn't mean it won't work.

Comment: Agreed - added some more details.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

```
new Date(day, month , yr);
```

Now look at the docs for the [deprecated `Date` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29):

```
public Date(int year,
    int month,
    int day)
```

Even if you'd got the arguments in the right order, the year would have been wrong, as the `Date` constructor is 1900-based.

*Don't* use deprecated members - they're deprecated for good reason.

Ideally, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) which is much better at date/time handling. But otherwise, use `Calendar.getTime()` to get a `Date` from a `Calendar`, rather than building it yourself.